# SharePoint Online when copying or moving information the destination lists won't load

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am the site collection administrator for our sharepoint sites. But for some reason recently I have been unable to move or copy information to different libraries that I have control over. The Choose destination just has a loading circle that never loads anything. Other uses are able to move and copy, so I am guessing that it's something to do with the caching of the sharepoint lists on my machine, but how do I resolve it.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Please clear the browser cache and compare the result.

And also consider your on-premises network that could cause the page loads slowly.

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/introduction-to-performance-tuning-for-sharepoint-online

Comment: Its seems to work ok for others in the office, and when I tried it at home on my own laptop I got the same result. So now thinking the problem might by with my permissions as Site administrator.

Comment: Please remove and re-add yourself as site collecction administrator and check the result.